# using python in maya do for-loop through selected nodes

Tags: python, for-loop, nodes, maya

I would like to know a few things here. I'm collecting all the selected nodes using this code snippet below. What I'm now wondering is...

1. How do I write a for-loop going through each node in the collection?
2. How do i get the total number of nodes in the collection?
3. How do I get the first node's position in the collection?
4. How do I get the last node's position in the collection?

   nodes = cmds.ls(long = True, selection = True, type = 'dagNode')

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.

```
for n in nodes:
    print n
```

2.

```
print len(nodes)
```

3.

```
print nodes[0]
```

4.

```
print nodes[-1]
```

Hope it will help you.

Comment: Just be careful not to rename or reparent things while working on the loop - that may change the name of the scene objects but will not update the list accordingly.